# Rolling Min in (n)Days Columns

Tags: python, pandas

**Dummy test data:**

```
np.random.seed(1)
ts = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(1000), index=pd.date_range('1/1/2000', periods=1000))
ts.columns = ['Val']
#ts['Week'] = ts.index.week
ts.loc['2000-01-30':]

    Val
2000-01-30  0.878143
2000-01-31  0.098347
2000-02-01  0.421108
2000-02-02  0.957890
2000-02-03  0.533165
2000-02-04  0.691877
2000-02-05  0.315516
2000-02-06  0.686501
2000-02-07  0.834626
```

First I filter the data:

```
tsSig = ts[ts.Val>.5]
```

Now the part I am struggling with.  I am able to create new columns showing the next (n) `mynums` days.

```
mynums = [1,2,3]
for i in mynums:
        tsSig['+'+str(+i)+'Days'] =  ts['Val'].ix[tsSig.index + pd.DateOffset(days=i)].values
```

This gives this output with `Val` output from (n)Days:

```
                 Val    Val_D1        +1Days    +2Days     +3Days
2000-01-02  0.720324    0.000114    0.000114    0.302333    0.146756
2000-01-10  0.538817    0.419195    0.419195    0.685220    0.204452
```

But what I actually want is a rolling min of these +nDays values like this:

**Desired output:**

```
                 Val    Val_D1        +1Days    +2Days     +3Days
2000-01-02  0.720324    0.000114    0.000114    0.000114    0.000114
2000-01-10  0.538817    0.419195    0.419195    0.419195    0.204452
```

Can someone please help?

Comment: Thanks for the answers.  Really interesting to see how you did this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another approach is transposing the dataframe, finding expanding min and transposing again:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(1)
ts = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(1000), index=pd.date_range('1/1/2000', periods=1000))
ts.columns = ['Val']
#ts['Week'] = ts.index.week

tsSig = ts[ts.Val>.5]

mynums = [1,2,3]
for i in mynums:
        tsSig.loc[:, '+'+str(+i)+'Days'] =  ts['Val'].ix[tsSig.index + pd.DateOffset(days=i)].values


tsSig = tsSig.T.expanding(0).min().T 


tsSig.head()
Out[103]: 
                 Val    +1Days    +2Days    +3Days
2000-01-02  0.720324  0.000114  0.000114  0.000114
2000-01-10  0.538817  0.419195  0.419195  0.204452
2000-01-12  0.685220  0.204452  0.204452  0.027388
2000-01-14  0.878117  0.027388  0.027388  0.027388
2000-01-16  0.670468  0.417305  0.417305  0.140387
```

Answer (score 1):

try `pd.concat`

```
rng = range(1, 5)
ts.join(pd.concat([ts.Val.rolling(i).min() for i in rng],
        axis=1, keys=['+{}Days'.format(i) for i in rng]))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

And another that reverses the entire frame so that forward rolling is possible.

```
tsSig2 = ts[::-1].shift().assign(Val=ts.Val[::-1],
                  plus1=lambda x: x.rolling(1).min(),
                  plus2=lambda x: x.rolling(2).min(), 
                  plus3=lambda x: x.rolling(3).min())[::-1].query('Val > .5')
```

And one more new solution thats better but requires prepending a small dummy frame.

```
ts_pre = pd.DataFrame(data=[[0]], index=pd.date_range('1/1/2000', periods=3), columns=['Val'])

tsSig2 = ts_pre.append(ts).assign(plus1=lambda x: x.shift(-1).rolling(1).min(),
                  plus2=lambda x: x.shift(-2).rolling(2).min(), 
                  plus3=lambda x: x.shift(-3).rolling(3).min()).query('Val > .5')
```

And one more way for good measure that is quite fast.

```
tsSig = ts.assign(plus1=lambda x: x.shift(-1),
                  plus2=lambda x: x.shift(-2), 
                  plus3=lambda x: x.shift(-3)).query('Val > .5')
tsSig[['plus1', 'plus2','plus3']] = tsSig[['plus1', 'plus2','plus3']].cummin(axis=1)
```